# array averaging by parts

Tags: r, excel, vba

I have two columns of data. First contains measured values, second contains descriptive string. I want to calculate average values in segments where "desc" is not changing. For example:

```
values  desc    avg
1       aa       1
1       aa       1
1       bb       2
2       bb       2
2       bb       2
3       bb       2
3       cc     5.5
8       cc     5.5
8       aa     3.5
2       aa     3.5
2       aa     3.5
2       aa     3.5
```

Column named "avg" is what I want to get. First and second row of avg contains mean value of the first two values (aa segment). Then follows mean value of bb segment (=2), then mean of cc segment and so on...

Is it possible in excel/vba or R?

Any help will be appreciated

mira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel you can use this formula in C2 coped down

`=IF(B2=B1,C1,AVERAGE(A2:INDEX(A2:A$1000,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B3:B$1000<>B2,0),0))))`

assumes you have up to 1000 rows of data - adjust as required

Comment: Thank you very much. Excelent solution!

Answer (score 2):

`ave` in R base is great for this task

```
> df$avg <- with(df, ave(values, desc, FUN=mean))
> df
   values desc avg
1       1  aaa 1.0
2       1  aaa 1.0
3       1   bb 2.0
4       2   bb 2.0
5       2   bb 2.0
6       3   bb 2.0
7       3   cc 5.5
8       8   cc 5.5
9       8   aa 3.5
10      2   aa 3.5
11      2   aa 3.5
12      2   aa 3.5
```

`data.table` is also awesome

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(df)
> dt[, avg:=mean(values), by="desc"]
> dt
```

Comment: I made a typo in my example- first segment should be "aa" - the very same as the last (updated). I wanted to ilustrate, that segments are repeated in the column. Your solution is cool, but not what I need. I do not want to average all values associated with "aa" or "cc" -just average each partial segment, no matter how many times it is repeated within the data set.

Comment: @mira: A way around this could be `with(df, ave(values, rep(make.unique(rle(df$desc)$values), rle(df$desc)$lengths), FUN=mean))` i.e. separate different partial segments of same `desc` and `ave` as Jilber answered.

Comment: @alexis_laz:   "Error in rle(df$desc) : 'x' must be an atomic vector", any hint?

Comment: @mira: I'm guessing your `df$desc` is a factor. Try `rle(as.character(df$desc))`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Jilber & alexis_laz.